# Room: "error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type". Building the right converter

Tags: android, database, class, option-type, typeconverter

I'm trying to build a TypeConverter for my custom class.

The class that needs the TypeConverter is this:

```
class Optional<out T>(val value: T? = null) {

    companion object {

        fun <T> of(value: T?): Optional<T> {
            return Optional(value)
        }

        fun <T> empty(): Optional<T> {
            return Optional()
        }
    }

    fun hasValue(): Boolean {
        return value != null
    }

}
```

This is my DAO method

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM item WHERE id = :id")
fun get(id: Long): Optional<ItemData>
```

And this my current TypeConverter for it

```
object OptionalConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun <T> fromOptional(optional: Optional<T>): T? {
        return if (!optional.hasValue()) null else optional.value
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun <T> toOptional(value: T): Optional<T> {
        return Optional(value)
    }    
}
```

When I build I get the following error

> error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type

Of course the problem is the TypeConverter. Is it possibile to do this way and use a TypeConverter for my Optional class?